# Sending string through fifo process in a single program

Tags: process, fifo, mknod

I'm having this fifo example in which the child process sends an integer to the parent process. I want it to send a string instead, but it doesn't work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void errexit(char *errMsg){
printf("\n About to exit: %s", errMsg);
fflush(stdout);
exit(1);
}

int main()
{
char ret;
pid_t pid;
char value;
char fifoName[]="/tmp/testfifo";
char errMsg[1000];
char input_string[30];
scanf("%s", input_string);
FILE *cfp;
FILE *pfp;

ret = mknod(fifoName, S_IFIFO | 0600, 0); 
/* 0600 gives read, write permissions to user and none to group and world */
if(ret < 0){
  sprintf(errMsg,"Unable to create fifo: %s",fifoName);
  errexit(errMsg);
}

pid=fork();
if(pid == 0){
/* child -- open the named pipe and write an integer to it */

  cfp = fopen(fifoName,"w");
  if(cfp == NULL) 
    errexit("Unable to open fifo for writing");
  ret=fprintf(cfp,"%s",input_string);
  fflush(cfp);
  exit(0);
} 

else{
  /* parent - open the named pipe and read an integer from it */
  pfp = fopen(fifoName,"r");
  if(pfp == NULL) 
    errexit("Unable to open fifo for reading");
  ret=fscanf(pfp,"%s",&value);
  if(ret < 0) 
    errexit("Error reading from named pipe");
  fclose(pfp);
  printf("This is the parent. Received value %d from child on fifo \n", value);
  unlink(fifoName); /* Delete the created fifo */
  exit(0);
}
```

}

I'm getting an error at 'ret=fscanf(pfp,"%s", value);', saying that %s expects char but value is type int, even if it isn't. it's declared as char.

What am I missing? I'm just trying to send a string to the parent and print it in there.

Comment: You could make your variable of type int like so: `int value;`. In your parent process you could use sth like `ret = fscanf(pfp, "%d", &value);` using %d instead of %s since you trying to read in an int type. If you then run the program and enter 4711 as value, then the output would be `This is the parent. Received value 4711 from child on fifo`.

Comment: thanks @stephanSchlecht, but I'm trying to send a string, not an int. And it doesn't work as it is now. do you know why? I'm getting that error I was describing.

Comment: if you want to do that then value needs to be a char array not a single char, so write `char value[32];` instead. Then you need to change your printf statement since it tries to interpret value as an int (%d), but you have to use %s. So the line could look like this `printf("This is the parent. Received value '%s' from child on fifo \n", value);` With this two changes it works.